# Movie about a family who takes in a religious stranger, that ends abruptly with an incoming asteroid

Tags: story-identification, movie

Many years ago I saw a movie that involved a family who took in a religious stranger. He turned out to be homicidal and tried to kill members of the family.

At the end the narrator quoted something the stranger said about God "pinching the stars out one by one..." and then a huge asteroid begins to block out the stars one by one and the asteroid is seen at the last minute, abruptly ending the movie.

Comment: Is this in any way fantasy? Did this man have superhuman abilities?

Comment: The approaching asteroid has an SF sound to it. The stranger having foreknowledge of the asteroid sounds fantastical to me as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is *The Final Storm* (2013).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Final_Storm_(film)):

> Set in the rural Pacific Northwest, **a mysterious character named Silas Hendershot (Luke Perry) takes refuge from a severe thunderstorm in a farm** owned by Tom (Steve Bacic) and Gillian Grady (Lauren Holly). He claims that he should stay and that they should watch after each other. Tom starts to dislike Silas and becomes suspicious of him and his past.
>
> *[...]*
>
> That night, Silas does return, however, and starts a fire as a distraction outside, which makes Tom run out to look for Silas. **Silas wraps a rope around Tom's neck and drags him up in the tree to hang, just like he did with his father.** Silas then goes into the house to talk to Tom's wife and try to persuade her to become his new wife. Tom's son comes to his rescue and cuts Tom down from the tree moments before he loses consciousness. A battle then ensues between Tom and Silas. Tom burns Silas alive by pushing him into the fire Silas created as the distraction.
>
> After the battle, Tom and his family notice that the stars in the sky start to glow and then disappear just as depicted in the Bible. Throughout the movie, Silas makes several references to the upcoming "end of the world", as well as the "rapture", as an explanation to the disappearance of the town's population and the fact that armed looters roam it. **Just before the end credits role, the entire universe is shown glowing very brightly, then disappearing, signifying the world's end.**

Notably, [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1331329/quotes/?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu) provides this quote:

> Silas Hendershot: In the end, the Almighty's just gonna reach down and pinch out the stars one by one.

The stars *literally* disappearing makes that sci-fi enough to be on-topic, I think.

---

Found with the Google query `"pinch * stars" site:imdb.com` which returns the above quote.